# Best tactic to avoid questions being put on hold?

Tags: discussion

What is the best tactic to avoid your questions being put on hold, if there is any? Surely it happens to everyone to ask a question in area you do not know much about. In this case following the rules of clarity is not always possible and asking naive questions happens, even more so when you are learning new things.

I am looking for any tips, rules of thumb, etc such as for example:

- Admit you do not know what you are asking for?
- Invite others to edit your question?
- Avoid editing your question at all cost?
- ...

Often you may ask a question you think is clear but because of lack of your knowledge in a specific area you may find yourself soon being criticized for asking questions that are nonsensical.

This makes me unsure whether to ask any questions at all in areas I have no expertise.

Here is one example: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/192682/1

Comment: I don't believe that _tactics_ actually add some value in the long term. So don't act in a tactical way, but just judge what you barely see and how it's relevant and productive for future research.

Comment: "Best tactic"?  Avoid asking questions that sound like they are primarily opinion based.

Comment: FWIW: your question is currently [being reviewed for reopening](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/86107) - if you have any other edits you can make that would clarify your core question, you should make them now. I would recommend at least summarizing your question as a closing.

Comment: I have changed the link to the original revision, because that's what was closed at the time when it was closed.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I thought your question is off-topic for the site. The suggestion to ask on some biomed forum seemed the most appropriate. (SE != Internet). This was actually said in one of the comments below your question (which I upvoted). However the restricted-list option presented in closure votes sometimes results in strangely [auto-]worded closures.

The way you've worded your question reads like you're serious about making a medical app[liance] not just a gimmick toy. There are countless issues with putting stuff not tested/compatible with human biology in people's mouths. You'll find out soon enough (if you're not doing a toy just for your own/friends use.) EE.SE isn't the site to go into biomed, I think. You'll get a lot of inappropriate advice. I know that by just reading some EE question on (especially safety related) on... say... superuser. (I'm still shaking my head at that.)

Comment: I'm not sure I agree

Comment: @Scott Seidman: After checking out your profile, I see your point. There are some biomed instrumentation experts here. :-)  But I'm not sure that invalidates my point about the average EE.SE user. After all, the most upvoted questions here are along the lines of how to solder two wires with arduino...